# Create a login theme for keycloak using vue+vuetify, not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, keycloak

I want to create a login page for keycloak using vue+vuetify.

I've followed some guides, and projects trying to acomplish this but, didn't have success at all. Actually I could  make it show some logs, but didn't rendered the app.

To summarize a little bit, the main idea was to have a project for each area of keycloak, like: [**login**,**account**,**register**].

So each project would have:

## App.vue

in this case is the code of login page.

## main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
const environment = document.querySelector('#environment');
if (environment) {
  console.log('environment has value');
  const environmentData = JSON.parse(environment.textContent)
  console.log(environmentData);
  Vue.config.productionTip = false
  Vue.prototype.$environment = environmentData;
  console.log('injected environment');
  new Vue({
    vuetify,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
  console.log('started vue app');
}
```

## index.ftl

```html
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.registrationLayout displayMessage=!messagesPerField.existsError('username','password') displayInfo=realm.password && realm.registrationAllowed && !registrationDisabled??; section>
  <#if section = "scripts">
    <script typo="module" src="${url.resourcesPath}/js/login.js"></script>
  </#if>
</@layout.registrationLayout>
```

## static(folder)

### theme.properties

```
locales=ca,cs,da,de,en,es,fr,hu,it,ja,lt,nl,no,pl,pt-BR,ru,sk,sv,tr,zh-CN
```

### template.ftl

```html
<#macro registrationLayout bodyClass="" displayInfo=false displayMessage=true displayRequiredFields=false showAnotherWayIfPresent=true>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="${properties.kcHtmlClass!}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>${msg("loginTitle",(realm.displayName!''))}</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
    <#nested "head">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script id="environment" type="application/json">
    {
      "urls": {
        "loginResetCredentials": "${url.loginResetCredentialsUrl}",
        "login": "${url.loginUrl}",
        "registration": "${url.registrationUrl}",
        "loginAction": "${url.loginAction}",
        "registrationAction": "${url.registrationAction}"
      },
      "titles": {
        "loginProfileTitle": "${msg("loginProfileTitle")}",
        "loginAccountTitle": "${msg("loginAccountTitle")}",
        "registerTitle": "${msg("registerTitle")}",
        "emailForgotTitle": "${msg("emailForgotTitle")}",
        "confirmLinkIdpTitle": "${msg("confirmLinkIdpTitle")}",
        "emailLinkIdpTitle": "${msg("emailLinkIdpTitle", idpDisplayName)}"
      },
      "permissions": {
        "usernameEditDisabled": <#if usernameEditDisabled??>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "loginWithEmailAllowed": <#if realm.loginWithEmailAllowed>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "registrationEmailAsUsername": <#if realm.registrationEmailAsUsername>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "rememberMe": <#if realm.rememberMe>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "resetPasswordAllowed": <#if realm.resetPasswordAllowed>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "password": <#if realm.password>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "registrationAllowed": <#if realm.registrationAllowed>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "registrationDisabled": <#if registrationDisabled??>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "passwordRequired": <#if passwordRequired??>true<#else>false</#if>
      },
      "labels": {
        "firstName": "${msg("firstName")}",
        "lastName": "${msg("lastName")}",
        "username": "${msg("username")}",
        "usernameOrEmail": "${msg("usernameOrEmail")}",
        "email": "${msg("email")}",
        "password": "${msg("password")}",
        "passwordConfirm": "${msg("passwordConfirm")}",
        "rememberMe": "${msg("rememberMe")}",
        "doForgotPassword": "${msg("doForgotPassword")}",
        "doLogIn": "${msg("doLogIn")}",
        "doSubmit": "${msg("doSubmit")}",
        "noAccount": "${msg("noAccount")}",
        "doRegister": "${msg("doRegister")}",
        "backToLogin": "${kcSanitize(msg("backToLogin"))?no_esc}",
        "confirmLinkIdpContinue": "${msg("confirmLinkIdpContinue")}",
        "doClickHere": "${msg("doClickHere")}"
      },
      "forms": {
        "loginUsername": "${(login.username!'')}",
        "loginRememberMe": <#if login.rememberMe??>true<#else>false</#if>,
        "selectedCredential": "${(auth.selectedCredential!'')}",
        "registerFirstName": <#if register??>"${(register.formData.firstName!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "registerLastName": <#if register??>"${(register.formData.lastName!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "registerEmail": <#if register??>"${(register.formData.email!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "registerUsername": <#if register??>"${(register.formData.username!'')}"<#else>""</#if>
      },
      "user": {
        "username": <#if user??>"${(user.username!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "email": <#if user??>"${(user.email!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "firstName": <#if user??>"${(user.firstName!'')}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "lastName": <#if user??>"${(user.lastName!'')}"<#else>""</#if>
      },
      "validations": {
        "firstName": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('firstName')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('firstName'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "lastName":  <#if messagesPerField.existsError('lastName')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('lastName'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "email": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('email')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('email'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "usernameOrPassword": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('username','password')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.getFirstError('username','password'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "username": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('username')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('username'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "password": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('password')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('password'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "passwordConfirm": <#if messagesPerField.existsError('password-confirm')>"${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('password-confirm'))?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>
      },
      "message": {
        "type": <#if displayMessage && message?has_content && (message.type != 'warning' || !isAppInitiatedAction??)>"${message.type}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "sumary": <#if displayMessage && message?has_content && (message.type != 'warning' || !isAppInitiatedAction??)>"${kcSanitize(message.summary)?no_esc}"<#else>""</#if>
      },
      "instruction": {
        "emailLinkIdp1": <#if emailLinkIdp1??>"${msg("emailLinkIdp1", idpDisplayName, brokerContext.username, realm.displayName)}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "emailLinkIdp2": <#if emailLinkIdp2??>"${msg("emailLinkIdp2")}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "emailLinkIdp3": <#if emailLinkIdp3??>"${msg("emailLinkIdp3")}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "emailLinkIdp4": <#if emailLinkIdp4??>"${msg("emailLinkIdp4")}"<#else>""</#if>,
        "emailLinkIdp5": <#if emailLinkIdp5??>"${msg("emailLinkIdp5")}"<#else>""</#if>
      },
      "social": [
        <#if realm.password && social.providers??>
          <#list social.providers as p>
            { 
              "alias": "${p.alias}",
              "displayName": "${p.displayName!}",
              "loginUrl": "${p.loginUrl}"
            }<#sep>, </#sep>
          </#list>
        </#if>
      ]
    }
  </script>
  <#nested "scripts">
</body>
</html>
</#macro>
```

## package.json

```json
{
  "name": "login",
  "theme":{
    "name":"customTheme"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "sass": "~1.32",
    "sass-loader": "^10.3.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off",
      "vue/multi-word-component-names": 0
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

## vue.config.js

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const packageJson = require('./package.json');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  configureWebpack:  {
    entry: () => {
      let entry = {}
      entry[packageJson.name] = path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        'src',
        'main.js'
      );
      return entry;
    },
    output: {
      filename: `keycloak/themes/${packageJson.theme.name}/${packageJson.name}/resources/js/[name].js`,
      publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.vue', '.json', '.scss'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),     
            '@hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src','hooks'),
            '@plugins': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src','plugins'),
            '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src','components'),         
        }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          loader: 'vue-loader',
          options: {
            extract: false
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                postcssOptions: {
                  plugins: { autoprefixer: {} }
                }
              }
            },
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'static'),
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'keycloak', 'themes', packageJson.theme.name, packageJson.name)
          },
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.ftl'),
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'keycloak', 'themes', packageJson.theme.name, packageJson.name,`${packageJson.name}.ftl`)
          },
        ]
      })
    ],
    ... {
          optimization: {
            removeAvailableModules: false,
            removeEmptyChunks: false,
            splitChunks: false
          }
        }
},
})
```

If you need more details, or if instead of creating a new app you want to clone my repo, here is the [link](https://github.com/dev-vinicius-andrade/keycloak-with-vue-vuetify-theme)

Reference projects:

[Vue TS project](https://github.com/jangaraj/vuetify-keycloak-theme)

[Proof of Concept of vuetify](https://github.com/jangaraj/vuetify-keycloak-theme/)

Comment: Did you get any further? Can you answer your own question by chance?

Comment: No, I didn't :/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.2.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.2.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    
    
    
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="344">
            <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/sunshine.jpg" height="200px" cover></v-img>
    
            <v-card-title>
                Top western road trips
            </v-card-title>
    
            <v-card-subtitle>
                1,000 miles of wonder
            </v-card-subtitle>
    
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn color="orange-lighten-2" variant="text">
                    Explore
                </v-btn>
    
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    
                <v-btn :icon="show ? 'mdi-chevron-up' : 'mdi-chevron-down'" @click="show = !show"></v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
    
            <v-expand-transition>
                <div v-show="show">
                    <v-divider></v-divider>
    
                    <v-card-text>
                        I'm a thing. But, like most politicians, he promised more than he could deliver. You won't have time
                        for sleeping, soldier, not with all the bed making you'll be doing. Then we'll go with that data
                        file! Hey, you add a one and two zeros to that or we walk! You're going to do his laundry? I've got
                        to find a way to escape.
                    </v-card-text>
                </div>
            </v-expand-transition>
        </v-card>
    </div>
    
    <script>

        const { createApp } = Vue
        const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

        const vuetify = createVuetify()

        const app = createApp()
        app.use(vuetify).mount('#app')

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can use CDN instance of package.json

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.2.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.2.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not seem to address the question at all. Please clarify in your answer how it responds to the given question.